# getting value of array check box and textbox in table

Tags: php, arrays

i'm a beginner in php and i'm hoping that somebody here can help me in this.

i have a table that has a check box to select an item and a text box to indicate the quantity the person wants to borrow. i was wondering how i can retrieve both these data and then save them in my database.

here is a part of my code:

```
<td width="30">
 <input id="optionsCheckbox" class="uniform_on" name="selector[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
 </td>
<td><?php echo $row['item_code']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['item_name']; ?></td>
<td align="center">
<img class="img-rounded" src="<?php echo $row['item_image'];?>" border="0" onMouseOver="showtrail('<?php echo $row['item_image'];?>','<?php echo $row['item_code'].": ".$row['item_name'];?> ',200,5)" onMouseOut="hidetrail()"></a></td>
<td><?php echo $row['item_quantity'] - $row['item_consumption']; ?> <?php echo $row['unit']; ?></td>
<td><input type="text" name="consume[]" pattern="[0-9]{1,4}"/></td>
```

here's what i have so far:

```
$id=$_POST['selector'];
$consume= $_POST['consume'];

$N = count($id);
for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
{

$query = $conn->query("select * from item where item_id ='$id[$i]'")or die(mysql_error());
$row = $query->fetch();
$code = $row['item_code'];
$name = $row['item_name'];

echo $code; echo $name; 
echo $id;


}
$x = count($consume);
for($y=0; $y < $x; $y++)
{echo $consume;
}
```

the echos are just for checking if the data goes through. i'm just making sure they do before i make a query for table insertion.

what i'm trying to do is to post them on another page, display them in a table (a la shopping cart) and then make the borrower fill out a form with his details.

---

ok, using gul's answer below, this is what i did:

```
$id = $_POST['selector'];
$consume = $_POST['consume'];

//array var for getting the values
$ids = ''; $consumes='';

//loop the posted array
for($i=0;$i<count($id);$i++)
{
$ids .= $id[$i].',';
$consumes.="'".$consume[$i]."',";
}

//remove the last comma
$ids = substr($ids,0,-1);
$consumes = substr($consumes,0,-1);

$query = $conn->query("select * from item where item_id IN($ids)")or die(mysql_error());

//table element
echo "<table border='1' style='border-collapse: 
collapse;border-color: silver;'>";  
echo "<tr style='font-weight: bold;'>";  
echo "<td width='150' align='center'>Item Code</td>"; 
echo "<td width='150' align='center'>Item Name</td>";
echo "<td width='150' align='center'>Quantity</td>";   
echo "</tr>"; 


//get data in table
$row = $query->fetch(); 
$code = $row['item_code'];
$name = $row['item_name'];
$table ="";
$table.="<tr>";
$table.="<td>".$code."</td>";
$table.="<td>".$name."</td>";
$table.="<td>".$consumes."</td>";
$table.="</tr>";

$table.="</table>";

//echo the table
echo $table;
```

however, when i select multiple items, only the last one shows up, but the consumes show up like this:

[image]

consume shows in one cell with single quotes and comma. help?

Comment: the selector part works, but i have no idea on how to post the value for the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
//first get the post
$id = $_POST['selector'];
 $consume = $_POST['consume'];

//array var for getting the values
$ids = ''; $consumes='';

//loop the posted array
for($i=0;$i<count($id);$i++)
{
   $ids .= $id[$i].',';
   //$consumes.="'".$consume[$i]."',";
}

//remove the last comma
$ids = substr($ids,0,-1);

$query = $conn->query("select * from item where item_id IN($ids))or die(mysql_error());

//table element
$table = "<table border='1'>";
$table.="<tr>";
$table.="<th>Code</th><th>Name</th>";
$table.="</tr>";
//get data in table
$row = $query->fetch();
$code = $row['item_code'];
$name = $row['item_name'];
$table.="<tr>";
$table.="<td>".$code."</td>";
$table.="<td>".$name."</td>";
$table.="</tr>";

$table.="</table>";

//echo the table
echo $table;
```

Comment: thanks, but how about the value for textbox consume?

Comment: is textbox array as well?

Comment: yes, for every item i have a textbox for the user to input how many of said item he wants to borrow.

Comment: thank you very much! can you tell me how to echo the results in a table? and how do i query using the selector id? sorry i'm just a newbie in php and this is my finals at school.

Comment: ok. i did this query `$query = $conn->query("select * from item where item_id ='$id[$i]'")or die(mysql_error());
$row = $query->fetch();
$code = $row['item_code'];
$name = $row['item_name'];

echo $code; echo $name; 
echo $id[$i]; $consume[$i];` and eveything works except for the $consume[$i] part. what do you think am i doing wrong?

Comment: Its not a good solution in your query, first concatenate selector values and then use in your query IN($ids).

Comment: Do not use query in your loop because it makes your system very slow

Comment: it's working now @gul-muhammad-akbari, thank you very much! you saved me my friend. but how do i display it in table?

Comment: sorry but i'm getting syntax error in the table part.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in C:\xampp\htdocs\con_ims\borrow_save.php on line 25.

Comment: ok i got it to work, however it only shows the first item selected.also consumes shows up with single quotes.  for example if i enter 2, it will show up in the table as '2'.  help?

Answer (score 0):

ok, so i tried this and it worked. thanks to gul for helping me.

```
$id = $_POST['selector'];
$consume = $_POST['consume'];

//array var for getting the values
$data = array();

//loop the posted array
for($i=0;$i<count($id);$i++)
{
$row = array('selector'=>$id[$i],'consume'=>$consume[$i]);
//push in array
array_push($data,$row);

$query = $conn->query("select * from item where item_id ='$id[$i]'")or die(mysql_error());
$row = $query->fetch();
$code = $row['item_code'];
$name = $row['item_name'];




    while ($row = $query->fetch()) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    }
    ?>
    <tr>

    <td><?php echo $code; ?></td> 
    <td><?php echo $name; ?></td> 
    <td><?php echo $consume[$i]; ?></td> 
    <td></td> 
    </tr>
<?php } ?>    

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: can someone help me please, it seems that consume only displays if i chose the items in order, if i skip one it doesn't display the value.

Comment: for example if i choose item with id= 1,2,3, consume displays correctly. but if i choose 1,3,5 or even just 3, consume doesn't show. help please. D: